# Check custom front camera availibility

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, surfaceview

I have been working on Custom SurfaceView Camera. I need to work with front camera as my application takes user's selfie.

For that I have checked a for whether front camera is available using below code.

```
public boolean checkFrontCamera() {
    int numCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    for (int i = 0; i < numCameras; i++) {
        Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
        if (CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT == info.facing) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Its working fine if device has both the camera, and it returns true. But if device has only one camera, this method always returns false as info.facing is 0 in this case and for the same in this code CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT is 1.

for Camera, I have used gms vision library. Below code is for camera source.

```
  CameraSource mCameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(context, detector)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(640, 480)
                .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
                .setRequestedFps(30.0f)
                .build();
```

Here I need to pass camera facing params.

Please provide if any other alternative. All solutions are welcomed.

Comment: It's fine this way. I think there is no android device with only front camera.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have a device in testing namely Lenovo Tab 2 A7-10F which has only front camera from where I come to know this issue.

Comment: Well in that case it doesn't count as front camera.

Comment: You want to use only front camera? and what action are you taking for devices which doesnt have a front cam?

Comment: If device does not have a front camera, application prompt user to about front camera not available, and use other device.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use this method, which returns the camera object

```
private Camera getCameraInstance() {
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        if (Camera.getNumberOfCameras() >= 2) {
            //Front facing camera
            c = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
        } else {
            // only has one camera (Rear)
            c = Camera.open();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}
```

Comment: Thanks, please see my edited question. I am using gms lib so camera opens based on camera.facing we pass.

Comment: And by this code it will open any primary camera it get if there is only one camera. I need to open only front camera if available or alert to user.